# Python FileSystemEventHandler with Process

Tags: python, python-2.7, process, queue, python-watchdog

I am trying to create a program that monitors a directory for changes. When a file is added to  the directory in question, FileHandler (a subclass of FileSystemEventHandler) will add the file path to the queue. A separate process called ConsumeQueue will periodically check the queue for items. If an item is found, it will get the file path fromt he queue and print it out to the console. Here is the source code for the program:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from Queue import Empty
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class FileHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
def __init__(self, q):
    super(FileHandler, self).__init__()
    self.q = q

def on_modified(self, event):
    if not event.is_directory and not 'thumbnail' in event.src_path:
        print "Created: " + event.src_path
        self.q.put(event.src_path)
        print 'Added', event.src_path, 'to queue', 'Queue size is now', self.q.qsize()

class ConsumeQueue(Process):
    def __init__(self, q):
        super(ConsumeQueue, self).__init__()
        print 'Initializing'
        self.q = q 

    def run(self):
        print 'Running'
        while True:
            try:
                value =  self.q.get(False)
                print 'Removed', value, 'from queue', 'Queue size is now', self.q.qsize()

            except Empty:
                print 'Nothing to process'
                time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()

    path = 'C:\path'
    event_handler = FileHandler(q)
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    consumer = ConsumeQueue(q)
    consumer.start()

    observer.join()
    consumer.join()
```

The problem with this is that while the observer seems to be adding items to the queue, the consumer is not running at all. I thought that the call consumer.start() would at least get it to run. What is the issue with my program?

Edit - Fixed the indentation.

Comment: Please use correct indentation when posting Python code.

Comment: The indentation is fixed.

Comment: 1) with `multiprocessing` (but not `threading`) the `qsize()` function is unreliable.  2) sometimes `print` is sketchy with multiple procs/threads.  Your code looks good for starting the consumer. What happens if you start *only* consumer and ignore the producer, do you get output?